# EditText height issue in Android 4.4 (Kitkat)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, height, padding

I am developing a sample app with just activation screen. I have one `EditText` and one `Button`.

In all android version screen is looking fine except Android 4.4.

I am getting issue with `EditText` in Kitkat version only. `EditText` not showing perfect height and also showing some shadow around `EditText`.

Please see below image for more detail.

[In Android 4.4 version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFQ4R.png)

[In Other Android version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cusoP.png)

Below is `EditText` code in layout xml file.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edt_activation_key"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:hint="Activation Number"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textColor="#575757"
                    android:textSize="15dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

How can I fit this issue with android 4.4. I also searched on Google too but not getting exact solution of this issue.

Comment: post some code for more understanding of your question

Comment: @Milind Vyas: Thanx for remember. actually i forgot to put code while posting question. btw check updated question.

Comment: now remove Textinput layout and run in 4.4 its remain same ?

Comment: Yesi also checked with this possibility. but its remain same. i checked with 2 different android devices having android 4.4 version.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. 
Use `android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText` instead of `EditText`
This solved the problem. Edited in your code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_activation_key"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Activation Number"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#575757"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```